# What does a "flag" means in DAL (Data access layer) table object

Tags: java, sql, database, jax-rs, data-access-layer

The code that I am reading looks like :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")
public interface DAL_Object {
     long condition_A_statisfied_Flag = 0x00000001;
     .
     .
     .
     @Id
     @Column(name="COLUMN1_NAME")
     .
     .
     .
}
```

What does these "flags" mean in the code? Is that some programming convention related to database or SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**condition_A_statisfied_Flag** is just a **long** type variable some one has declared in this "DAL_Object" interface. And 1 is assigned to this variable. This has nothing to do with database or sql.

```
long condition_A_statisfied_Flag = 0x00000001;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think you are right, this might just be some bit mask which marks the definition of each bit in one of the member variable.

Comment: Given that this is not related to DB, what does a flag means in in database or SQL? I always saw this term in the documentation, but cannot find any instructions online.